# Change permanently the priority of all process started by user

Tags: server, 18.10, process-priority

I have an application on my server that needs to be given more resources and priority than everything else.

The easiest thing to do would probably be to raise the priority of the two users it runs as

How would I do that in a permanent fashion?

**NOTE** I do not refer to 'niceness', especially as there is no way to permanently set that.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the OOM Killer's priority and how it chooses what to kill: https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html

In particular: `badness_for_task = total_vm_for_task / (sqrt(cpu_time_in_seconds) * sqrt(sqrt(cpu_time_in_minutes)))`

So you can give it a higher "priority" by having it use more CPU and less virtual memory.

You can also set `/proc/[pid]/oom_adj` to -17 for all processes of the user.  this effectively makes it unkillable: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

Comment: First off, I can't control how much ram or cpu it uses. Second, I ask because an application that uses more ram (Firefox) isn't getting killed, but my other much more important one is. Also that isn't permanent - what if the pic change on reboot?

Comment: And how do I set that value anyway?

Comment: First comment pic should be pid. Autocorrect

Comment: you can get a list of pid's for the user with `pgrep -u $USER`.  i understand this isn't a great solution, but i don't know if there is a better one.

Comment: using that command, I can use a cron job to set niceness. Still not sure how to set /proc/[pid]/oom_adj

Comment: if the cron job runs as root, you can add `echo -17 > /proc/$pid/oom_adj`.  If you're not looping already, you will need to loop over the pid's from `pgrep`